# How to pass parameters from WebService to stored procedure with XML

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, web-services

I would like to pass parameters into my stored procedure. I'm newbie in this topic. I have URL request, content to send type xml and using post method it return me xml response. Now I would get this data using xlmserializer and pass to stored procedure. Have you some info, materials how to do that?
This is my XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://xmlsoap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://xmlsoap" xmlns:soap="http://xmlsoap">
    <soap:Body>
        <listCarsResponse xmlns="http://www.webservice">
            <cars>
                <car name="Toyota" car_id="1" />
            </cars>
        </listCarsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: How does your XML look like? It might be simpler to pass the XML-parameter *as-is* and do the shredding within SQL Server Stored Procedure...

Comment: The input XML will always have the same structure? What you want to do with that data?

Comment: @gofr...No, input XML structure receives various parameters. I have to pass parameters from all XML response to the revelant procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The shredding with SQL would look like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://xmlsoap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://xmlsoap" xmlns:soap="http://xmlsoap">
    <soap:Body>
        <listCarsResponse xmlns="http://www.webservice">
            <cars>
                <car name="Toyota" car_id="1" />
            </cars>
        </listCarsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://xmlsoap' AS [soap]
                  ,'http://www.webservice' AS innerDefault)
SELECT c.value('(innerDefault:car/@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CarName
      ,c.value('(innerDefault:car/@car_id)[1]','int') AS Car_Id
FROM @xml.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/innerDefault:listCarsResponse') AS A(lcr)
CROSS APPLY lcr.nodes('innerDefault:cars') AS B(c);
```

The result

```
CarName Car_Id
Toyota  1
```

### UPDATE Same in a stored procedure

--I pass in the parameter as `VARACHAR(MAX)` otherwise you might get a problem with the `utf-8`...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProc(@XMLasString VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    --cast it to XML
    DECLARE @xml XML=CAST(@XMLasString AS XML);

    WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://xmlsoap' AS [soap]
                      ,'http://www.webservice' AS innerDefault)
    SELECT c.value('(innerDefault:car/@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CarName
          ,c.value('(innerDefault:car/@car_id)[1]','int') AS Car_Id
    FROM @xml.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/innerDefault:listCarsResponse') AS A(lcr)
    CROSS APPLY lcr.nodes('innerDefault:cars') AS B(c);

END
GO
```

--Here I create it as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, just to show, that this is passed in as *non-unicode* and therefore will not break due to the `utf-8`

DECLARE @parameter NVARCHAR(MAX)=
    N'
    
        
            
                
                    
                
            
        
    ';

```
EXEC dbo.YourProc @XmlAsString=@parameter
```

--Clean-Up

```
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.YourProc;
```